# Xamarin ios: loaded the nib but the view outlet was not set

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross, mvxbind

I’m new in xamarin ios and I need to add view in existing project. Project use mvvmcross framework.
I’ve done:

1. Created PerevozkiViewModelClass :MvxViewModel in Core project
2. Add UI View controller with storydoard (P.S. BaseView extends MvxViewController)[image]

   > public partial class PerevozkiView : BaseView
   >       {
   >           public PerevozkiView() : base("PerevozkiView", null)
   >           {
   >           }
   >
   > ```
   >     public override void ViewDidLoad()
   >     {
   >         base.ViewDidLoad();
   >
   >         var set = this.CreateBindingSet<PerevozkiView, PerevozkiViewModel>();
   >         set.Apply();
   >     }
   >
   > }
   > ```
3. Delete PerevozkiView.Storyboard

4.Add PerevozkiView.xib and in file owner specify PerevozkiView (I cant choose it from list, so I just hardcode “PerevozkiView as file owner)[image]

5. After deploy in IOS simulator I’ve got exception:
   Foundation.MonoTouchException
   Сообщение = Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "PerevozkiView" nib but the view outlet was not set here in Main:

   > ```
   >  public class Application
   >     {
   >         // This is the main entry point of the application.
   >         static void Main(string[] args)
   >         {
   >             // if you want to use a different Application Delegate class from "AppDelegate"
   >             // you can specify it here.
   >             UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");
   >         }
   >     }
   > ```

I have no idea what is wrong. Pls help

Comment: "I cant choose it from list, so I just hardcode “PerevozkiView as file owner" how do you hardcode this? The selected option shows "Pere".

Comment: @JKL i have specified full name "PerevozkiView". I attach this screen to show that i have no autocomplete because PerevozkiView for any reason is out from list of classes

Comment: Did you ever get his figured out? I'm running into the same issue.